# locate Vala/Sqlite3 memory leak

Tags: c, sqlite, valgrind, vala

part of my application is a daemon that runs in the background and regularly collects data and writes it to the sqlite3 database.
Sadly the process seems to leak a bit of memory every "sync" (getting data and writing it to the db).
What I basically do is: create a new thread where the whole sync process takes place, create some empty "Gee.LinkedList", pass them to some functions to fill them, then pass them to other functions to write them to the db. I am not aware of any leftover references to the LinkedList's after the process is done. So theoretically the data should be freed. I checked the reference count of the object shortly before running out of scope and it was 1. I there a way to check if a object has been successfully freed?
I tried using valgrind to see if I can detect the problem in my code.
Valgrind detects tons of "possibly lost" memory, all pointing towards functions where I interact with sqlite3.

```
==5038== 2,078,576 bytes in 1,594 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4,283 of 4,283
==5038==    at 0x4C28C50: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5038==    by 0x535E666: sqlite3MemMalloc (sqlite3.c:17913)
==5038==    by 0x533BC02: mallocWithAlarm (sqlite3.c:21581)
==5038==    by 0x533BC02: sqlite3Malloc (sqlite3.c:21612)
==5038==    by 0x533EA46: pcache1Alloc (sqlite3.c:41451)
==5038==    by 0x534534A: pcache1AllocPage (sqlite3.c:41545)
==5038==    by 0x534534A: pcache1FetchStage2 (sqlite3.c:41995)
==5038==    by 0x53712E4: sqlite3PcacheFetch (sqlite3.c:40697)
==5038==    by 0x53712E4: sqlite3PagerAcquire (sqlite3.c:48339)
==5038==    by 0x537806C: accessPayload (sqlite3.c:59076)
==5038==    by 0x537A1F7: vdbeMemFromBtreeResize (sqlite3.c:65928)
==5038==    by 0x53993F6: sqlite3VdbeExec (sqlite3.c:75460)
==5038==    by 0x539A83E: sqlite3Step (sqlite3.c:71540)
==5038==    by 0x539A83E: sqlite3_step (sqlite3.c:71601)
==5038==    by 0x420639: feed_reader_db_manager_update_articles (in /usr/bin/feedreader-daemon)
==5038==    by 0x44693B: feed_reader_feed_server_getArticles (in /usr/bin/feedreader-daemon)
==5038==    by 0x440B44: __lambda11_ (in /usr/bin/feedreader-daemon)
==5038==    by 0x440E46: ___lambda11__gthread_func (in /usr/bin/feedreader-daemon)
==5038==    by 0xAECE834: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4600.1)
==5038==    by 0xB861609: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.22.so)
==5038==    by 0xB59BBBC: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
```

The function mentioned in the valgrind log looks like this:

```
public void update_articles(Gee.LinkedList<article> articles)
{
    executeSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION");

    var update_query = new QueryBuilder(QueryType.UPDATE, "main.articles");
    update_query.updateValuePair("unread", "$UNREAD");
    update_query.updateValuePair("marked", "$MARKED");
    update_query.updateValuePair("tags", "$TAGS");
    update_query.updateValuePair("lastModified", "$LASTMODIFIED");
    update_query.addEqualsCondition("articleID", "$ARTICLEID");
    update_query.build();

    Sqlite.Statement stmt;
    int ec = sqlite_db.prepare_v2 (update_query.get(), update_query.get().length, out stmt);

    if (ec != Sqlite.OK)
        logger.print(LogMessage.ERROR, "upate_articles: %s".printf(sqlite_db.errmsg()));

    int unread_position = stmt.bind_parameter_index("$UNREAD");
    int marked_position = stmt.bind_parameter_index("$MARKED");
    int tags_position = stmt.bind_parameter_index("$TAGS");
    int modified_position = stmt.bind_parameter_index("$LASTMODIFIED");
    int articleID_position = stmt.bind_parameter_index("$ARTICLEID");
    assert (unread_position > 0);
    assert (marked_position > 0);
    assert (tags_position > 0);
    assert (modified_position > 0);
    assert (articleID_position > 0);


    foreach(var article in articles)
    {
        stmt.bind_text(unread_position, article.getUnread().to_string());
        stmt.bind_text(marked_position, article.getMarked().to_string());
        stmt.bind_text(tags_position, article.getTagString());
        stmt.bind_int (modified_position, article.getLastModified());
        stmt.bind_text(articleID_position, article.getArticleID());

        while(stmt.step() != Sqlite.DONE) {}
        stmt.reset();
    }

    executeSQL("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
}
```

I also tried checking the generated c-code for any obvious bugs, but without success. But maybe I overlooked something? Its pretty messy:

```
void feed_reader_db_manager_update_articles (FeedReaderdbManager* self, GeeLinkedList* articles) {
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* update_query = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp0_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp1_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp2_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp3_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp4_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp5_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp6_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp7_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp8_ = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;
gint ec = 0;
sqlite3* _tmp9_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp10_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp11_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp12_ = NULL;
FeedReaderQueryBuilder* _tmp13_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp14_ = NULL;
gchar* _tmp15_ = NULL;
gint _tmp16_ = 0;
gint _tmp17_ = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp18_ = NULL;
gint _tmp19_ = 0;
gint _tmp20_ = 0;
gint _tmp21_ = 0;
gint unread_position = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp27_ = NULL;
gint _tmp28_ = 0;
gint marked_position = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp29_ = NULL;
gint _tmp30_ = 0;
gint tags_position = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp31_ = NULL;
gint _tmp32_ = 0;
gint modified_position = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp33_ = NULL;
gint _tmp34_ = 0;
gint articleID_position = 0;
sqlite3_stmt* _tmp35_ = NULL;
gint _tmp36_ = 0;
gint _tmp37_ = 0;
gint _tmp38_ = 0;
gint _tmp39_ = 0;
gint _tmp40_ = 0;
gint _tmp41_ = 0;
#line 651 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
g_return_if_fail (self != NULL);
#line 651 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
g_return_if_fail (articles != NULL);
#line 653 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_db_manager_executeSQL (self, "BEGIN TRANSACTION");
#line 655 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp0_ = feed_reader_query_builder_new (FEED_READER_QUERY_TYPE_UPDATE, "main.articles");
#line 655 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
update_query = _tmp0_;
#line 656 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp1_ = update_query;
#line 656 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_query_builder_updateValuePair (_tmp1_, "unread", "$UNREAD");
#line 657 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp2_ = update_query;
#line 657 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_query_builder_updateValuePair (_tmp2_, "marked", "$MARKED");
#line 658 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp3_ = update_query;
#line 658 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_query_builder_updateValuePair (_tmp3_, "tags", "$TAGS");
#line 659 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp4_ = update_query;
#line 659 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_query_builder_updateValuePair (_tmp4_, "lastModified", "$LASTMODIFIED");
#line 660 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp5_ = update_query;
#line 660 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_query_builder_addEqualsCondition (_tmp5_, "articleID", "$ARTICLEID", TRUE, FALSE);
#line 661 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp6_ = update_query;
#line 661 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp7_ = feed_reader_query_builder_build (_tmp6_);
#line 661 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp8_ = _tmp7_;
#line 661 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_g_free0 (_tmp8_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp9_ = self->priv->sqlite_db;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp10_ = update_query;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp11_ = feed_reader_query_builder_get (_tmp10_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp12_ = _tmp11_;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp13_ = update_query;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp14_ = feed_reader_query_builder_get (_tmp13_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp15_ = _tmp14_;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp16_ = strlen (_tmp15_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp17_ = _tmp16_;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp19_ = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (_tmp9_, _tmp12_, _tmp17_, &_tmp18_, NULL);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_sqlite3_finalize0 (stmt);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
stmt = _tmp18_;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp20_ = _tmp19_;
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_g_free0 (_tmp15_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_g_free0 (_tmp12_);
#line 664 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
ec = _tmp20_;
#line 666 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp21_ = ec;
#line 666 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
if (_tmp21_ != SQLITE_OK) {
#line 5122 "DB_Manager.c"
    FeedReaderLogger* _tmp22_ = NULL;
    sqlite3* _tmp23_ = NULL;
    const gchar* _tmp24_ = NULL;
    gchar* _tmp25_ = NULL;
    gchar* _tmp26_ = NULL;
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp22_ = feed_reader_logger;
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp23_ = self->priv->sqlite_db;
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp24_ = sqlite3_errmsg (_tmp23_);
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp25_ = g_strdup_printf ("upate_articles: %s", _tmp24_);
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp26_ = _tmp25_;
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    feed_reader_logger_print (_tmp22_, FEED_READER_LOG_MESSAGE_ERROR, _tmp26_);
#line 667 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _g_free0 (_tmp26_);
#line 5142 "DB_Manager.c"
}
#line 669 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp27_ = stmt;
#line 669 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp28_ = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index (_tmp27_, "$UNREAD");
#line 669 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
unread_position = _tmp28_;
#line 670 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp29_ = stmt;
#line 670 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp30_ = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index (_tmp29_, "$MARKED");
#line 670 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
marked_position = _tmp30_;
#line 671 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp31_ = stmt;
#line 671 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp32_ = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index (_tmp31_, "$TAGS");
#line 671 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
tags_position = _tmp32_;
#line 672 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp33_ = stmt;
#line 672 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp34_ = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index (_tmp33_, "$LASTMODIFIED");
#line 672 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
modified_position = _tmp34_;
#line 673 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp35_ = stmt;
#line 673 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp36_ = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index (_tmp35_, "$ARTICLEID");
#line 673 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
articleID_position = _tmp36_;
#line 674 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp37_ = unread_position;
#line 674 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_vala_assert (_tmp37_ > 0, "unread_position > 0");
#line 675 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp38_ = marked_position;
#line 675 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_vala_assert (_tmp38_ > 0, "marked_position > 0");
#line 676 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp39_ = tags_position;
#line 676 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_vala_assert (_tmp39_ > 0, "tags_position > 0");
#line 677 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp40_ = modified_position;
#line 677 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_vala_assert (_tmp40_ > 0, "modified_position > 0");
#line 678 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_tmp41_ = articleID_position;
#line 678 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_vala_assert (_tmp41_ > 0, "articleID_position > 0");
#line 5194 "DB_Manager.c"
{
    GeeLinkedList* _article_list = NULL;
    GeeLinkedList* _tmp42_ = NULL;
    GeeLinkedList* _tmp43_ = NULL;
    gint _article_size = 0;
    GeeLinkedList* _tmp44_ = NULL;
    gint _tmp45_ = 0;
    gint _tmp46_ = 0;
    gint _article_index = 0;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp42_ = articles;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp43_ = _g_object_ref0 (_tmp42_);
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _article_list = _tmp43_;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp44_ = _article_list;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp45_ = gee_abstract_collection_get_size ((GeeCollection*) _tmp44_);
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _tmp46_ = _tmp45_;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _article_size = _tmp46_;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _article_index = -1;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    while (TRUE) {
#line 5222 "DB_Manager.c"
        gint _tmp47_ = 0;
        gint _tmp48_ = 0;
        gint _tmp49_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* article = NULL;
        GeeLinkedList* _tmp50_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp51_ = 0;
        gpointer _tmp52_ = NULL;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp53_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp54_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* _tmp55_ = NULL;
        FeedReaderArticleStatus _tmp56_ = 0;
        gchar* _tmp57_ = NULL;
        GDestroyNotify _tmp58_ = NULL;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp59_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp60_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* _tmp61_ = NULL;
        FeedReaderArticleStatus _tmp62_ = 0;
        gchar* _tmp63_ = NULL;
        GDestroyNotify _tmp64_ = NULL;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp65_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp66_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* _tmp67_ = NULL;
        gchar* _tmp68_ = NULL;
        GDestroyNotify _tmp69_ = NULL;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp70_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp71_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* _tmp72_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp73_ = 0;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp74_ = NULL;
        gint _tmp75_ = 0;
        FeedReaderarticle* _tmp76_ = NULL;
        gchar* _tmp77_ = NULL;
        GDestroyNotify _tmp78_ = NULL;
        sqlite3_stmt* _tmp81_ = NULL;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp47_ = _article_index;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _article_index = _tmp47_ + 1;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp48_ = _article_index;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp49_ = _article_size;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        if (!(_tmp48_ < _tmp49_)) {
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
            break;
#line 5269 "DB_Manager.c"
        }
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp50_ = _article_list;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp51_ = _article_index;
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp52_ = gee_abstract_list_get ((GeeAbstractList*) _tmp50_, _tmp51_);
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        article = (FeedReaderarticle*) _tmp52_;
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp53_ = stmt;
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp54_ = unread_position;
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp55_ = article;
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp56_ = feed_reader_article_getUnread (_tmp55_);
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp57_ = feed_reader_article_status_to_string (_tmp56_);
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp58_ = g_free;
#line 683 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_bind_text (_tmp53_, _tmp54_, _tmp57_, -1, _tmp58_);
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp59_ = stmt;
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp60_ = marked_position;
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp61_ = article;
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp62_ = feed_reader_article_getMarked (_tmp61_);
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp63_ = feed_reader_article_status_to_string (_tmp62_);
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp64_ = g_free;
#line 684 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_bind_text (_tmp59_, _tmp60_, _tmp63_, -1, _tmp64_);
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp65_ = stmt;
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp66_ = tags_position;
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp67_ = article;
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp68_ = feed_reader_article_getTagString (_tmp67_);
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp69_ = g_free;
#line 685 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_bind_text (_tmp65_, _tmp66_, _tmp68_, -1, _tmp69_);
#line 686 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp70_ = stmt;
#line 686 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp71_ = modified_position;
#line 686 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp72_ = article;
#line 686 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp73_ = feed_reader_article_getLastModified (_tmp72_);
#line 686 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_bind_int (_tmp70_, _tmp71_, _tmp73_);
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp74_ = stmt;
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp75_ = articleID_position;
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp76_ = article;
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp77_ = feed_reader_article_getArticleID (_tmp76_);
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp78_ = g_free;
#line 687 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_bind_text (_tmp74_, _tmp75_, _tmp77_, -1, _tmp78_);
#line 689 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        while (TRUE) {
#line 5343 "DB_Manager.c"
            sqlite3_stmt* _tmp79_ = NULL;
            gint _tmp80_ = 0;
#line 689 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
            _tmp79_ = stmt;
#line 689 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
            _tmp80_ = sqlite3_step (_tmp79_);
#line 689 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
            if (!(_tmp80_ != SQLITE_DONE)) {
#line 689 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
                break;
#line 5354 "DB_Manager.c"
            }
        }
#line 690 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _tmp81_ = stmt;
#line 690 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        sqlite3_reset (_tmp81_);
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
        _g_object_unref0 (article);
#line 5363 "DB_Manager.c"
    }
#line 681 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
    _g_object_unref0 (_article_list);
#line 5367 "DB_Manager.c"
}
#line 693 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
feed_reader_db_manager_executeSQL (self, "COMMIT TRANSACTION");
#line 651 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_sqlite3_finalize0 (stmt);
#line 651 "/home/jeanluc/Projects/FeedReader/master/src/DB_Manager.vala"
_g_object_unref0 (update_query);
#line 5375 "DB_Manager.c"
}
```

Any sort of hints how I can track down this problem are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Rebuillding libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 with debugging symbols won't solve the problem but may help figuring out the cause. Just place it in the current directory and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

Comment: @arsv: thx, but I still have no idea what could be wrong :D now the output looks like this: http://pastebin.com/N5Pu2JNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think you have a memory leak?

If a Vala reference counted object has a count of 1 before going out of scope it will be freed by the unref, I believe. On the Vala side you should be aware GLib can confuse Valgrind by using its own heap calls - see [Valgrind reports memory 'possibly lost' when using glib data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254610/valgrind-reports-memory-possibly-lost-when-using-glib-data-types) . I think there is a suppression file for Valgrind for this somewhere.

It looks as though the Valgrind report you have pasted in your question is saying SQLite is not freeing its memory after `step`. Could this be a caching thing as suggested in [Is there any memory leak in the normal routine of sqlite3_*()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703720/is-there-any-memory-leak-in-the-normal-routine-of-sqlite3)

I'm curious why Vala line numbers aren't showing in Valgrind as you have the `--debug` flag set for the C output.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a memory leak, because the memory footprint of the daemon-process keeps growing with every sync. It starts out at 30mb and after a day it can grow to over 100mb and a user of the app reported finding out his daemon process was consuming 2.4GB after quite some uptime. But I will deactivate caching for sqlite and test some more. Thx :)

Comment: OK, that's a lot :) How many requests in a day? As you are using a new thread each time, are you then finalising the prepared statement and closing the database as advised in [Dynamic Memory Allocation In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html) ? A less likely possibility might be an error from `exec()`, this has to have the memory freed - https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html You seem to have a separate function, `executeSQL`, just for some simple SQL (begin and end transaction). Could there be a frequent un-freed error in there?

Comment: after disabling caching in sqlite all the "noise" in the valgrind log disappeared and I see quite some memory leaked in another part of the application that interacts with libxml2. That actually makes way more sense now. Thx a lot :) I will see how far I get and post a resolution to my problem or more questions as soon as I dig deeper :)

Comment: Okay, I fixed a lot of libxml2 stuff (you have to manually manage your memory there most of the time) and are now left with 2 "definitly lost" warnings. The first one is a one-time-thing with the glib main loop, so not too much trouble. The second warning is about "Secret.password_lookupv_sync()". The documentation suggest to free the password when it's not needed anymore, but I want to return it from the function. So what should I do? http://pastebin.com/VSLYAtDA

Comment: You should follow the StackOverflow format and accept my answer as the one that answered your question ;-) If you think it gave you the hint you asked for that is. Then start a new question. A quick look at your pastebin suggests there is a closure (callback) somewhere that is causing the leak, it also makes me wonder why you are doing `pwSchema.unref();` instead of letting Vala deal with it.